# In-app settings controlled by plist?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, settings, plist

Is there a library or good tutorial which covers creating in-app settings, like this:
http://img.skitch.com/20090625-s8bf6ahybwe3cesd1id38h3nt.jpg

What I would like is if it:

- doesn't use the built-in Settings app, and does not replicate it's settings in the Settings app
- is controlled by a plist file with various Dictionaries and Arrays
- creates a nice looking table view
- allows edit-in-place text fields as well as switches and sliders and ticks etc
- doesn't have any of the annoying problems I've come across when trying to build my own version (not scrolling to show the textfield, cells disappearing)

JUST TO EMPHASIZE: I DO NOT WANT THE SETTINGS TO APPEAR IN THE SETTINGS APP.

It would appear that the iphone dev world is crying out for such a thing.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Why *NOT* have them in the Settings app as well?  For people who expect settings to be there, they'll be there.  For people who want it in your app, they'll be there too.  Seems like a definite win-win for everyone involved.  Plus you wouldn't have to write a custom settings-ui-generating framework.

Comment: Because I want to keep them in the Keychain for the security needs of the client.

Answer (score 4):

[InAppSettingsKit](http://www.InAppSettingsKit.com/)

Comment: The settings appear in the Settings app. I want them to only appear within the app.

Comment: InAppSettingsKit can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the open source project [InAppSettings](http://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home), and it works well.

Comment: The settings appear in the Settings app. I want them to only appear within the app.

Comment: Ok, the way you originally worded it, it sounded like you were happy as long as it replicated its settings.

Comment: +1 I've used this, and it's seamless and terrifically easy to integrate